# Variables in GNU Make recipes, is that possible?

Tags: make

Is it possible to have variables in GNU Make recipes?

Something like this doesn't work:

```
%_t.mkd : %.mkd
    REV=$$(svn info $<|grep 'Last Changed Rev'|cut -f4 -d\ )
    echo $${REV}
```

Is there some way to make that work at all?

As you can see what I want is to extract the revision that a file was changed and then use that later in the full recipe.  Unfortunately I can't use `svn:keywords` as I need the revision number outside of the document in question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `make` tool starts a new shell process for each recipe line. And shell variables – even 'exported' environment variables – cannot possibly propagate "upwards"; they're gone as soon as the shell process exits.

- The traditional method is to join the recipe lines using `\` in the Makefile:

  ```
  foo: bar baz
      line1; \
      line2; \
      line3
  ```

  (Note that the commands must be separated using `;` or `&&`, because the backslashes are also passed to the shell which does the same line-joining.)

  See also [`info make "Splitting Lines"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Lines.html) and [`info make "Splitting Recipe Lines"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html) in the GNU Make manual.
- The other method is to tell `make` to always use one shell process for the entire recipe, using the `.ONESHELL` directive:

  ```
  .ONESHELL:

  foo: bar baz
      line1
      line2
      line3
  ```

  See [`info make "One Shell"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

  (Note that while `.ONESHELL` is recommended by POSIX, [not all make versions support it](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=770); e.g. BSD make only has a command-line flag for it. This shouldn't be a problem though.)

Answer (score 24):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519234/cant-assign-variable-inside-recipe

This is the solution to change a variable in a recipe:

> ```
> recipe: 
>         $(eval variablename=whatever)
> ```

Answer (score 5):

taking what @user3645902 mentioned, here is the solution to the main question:

```
recipe:
    @$(eval REV=`svn info $<|grep 'Last Changed Rev'|cut -f4 -d`)
    @echo $(REV)
```

Comment: I believe that this creates a race condition. Two recipes executing in parallel could stomp on each others' variables.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Gnu Make 6.5 Setting Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting):

> The shell assignment operator `!=` can be used to execute a program
>   and set a variable to its output. This operator first evaluates the
>   right-hand side, then passes that result to the shell for execution.
>   If the result of the execution ends in a newline, that one newline is
>   removed; all other newlines are replaced by spaces. The resulting
>   string is then placed into the named recursively-expanded variable.

So you could try the following (not tested):

```
REV != $$(svn info $<|grep 'Last Changed Rev'|cut -f4 -d\ ) \
echo $${REV}
```

Comment: This would work at the top level of a makefile, but not in the middle of a recipe (where shell syntax is used, not Make syntax). It'd be `REV != svn info ...` too.

Comment: Nope, as you see I need it as part of the recipe since the value will be different for different files.

Answer (score 0):

this way of setting undef Makefile function parameter in this case `$(1)`  argument works:

```
# usage:
# install-api-node:
#   $(call install-img,linux_user)

define install-img

    APPUSR=$(eval APPUSR=`echo appusr`)
    APPUSR=$(or $(1),$(APPUSR))
   
    @echo example usage : docker run -it -d --restart=always \
        -v $$(pwd):/opt/project-source-dir \
        -v $$HOME/.aws:/home/$(APPUSR)/.aws \
        --name my-container my-image ;


endef
```